# Need to add function to infoBox onclose

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to add a function to closeclick for a google maps infoBox. I read some other entries in stackoverflow, but according to them, this should work. This function has several listeners being added, and they all work accordingly, except for the closeclick for the marker's infoBox. Is there any obvious mistake I am overlooking? Thank you in advance.

```
google.maps.Map.prototype.addPushpinMarker = function(pp/*JSMapPushpin*/)
{

/* accuracy radius */
if (pp.accRadius) {
    pp.accRadius.setMap(this);
}

/* pushpins */
if (pp.bgMarker) {
    pp.bgMarker.setMap(this);
}
pp.marker.setMap(this);

/* save */
this.pushpinMarkers.push(pp);


/* info-balloon 'click' listener */
var self = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(pp.marker, 'click', function(event) {
    //isClicked = true; 
    self.showPushpinPopup(pp);
    console.log("Is clicked");
});
google.maps.event.addListener(pp.marker.infoWindow, 'closeclick', function(event) {
    pp.marker.infoWindowOpen = false;
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(pp.marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    //isClicked = false;
    self.showPushpinPopup1(pp);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(pp.marker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
    if(!isClicked){
            console.log("mouse out");
            //this.hidePushpinPopups();
            self.hideToolTip();
    }
});

};
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `closeclick` event?

Comment: I want the infowindowopen value of the marker set to false. I'm actually working on someone else's code and they didn't have the infowindowopen set to false when a user closes the infowindow.

Comment: pp.marker.infoWindowOpen = false; does this change the infoWindowOpen property in general? You should check out if it works by putting it outside the click listner. If it doesn't, then there's something wrong with the way you try to set the property to false. There's probably a set() function for infoWindowOpen property.

Comment: No, it works when I put it outside the listener function. I did this as a work-around to address this issue, but it looks kind of weird, so I still wanna figure out why this is happening.